# Change wordpress slug from url using .htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I am developing website using wordpress. I have slug something like

> www.example.com/topic/topic1/content-of-topic1

Whenever any user try to go above page, It should point to

> www.example.com/topic1/content-of-topic1

I tried to change using htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^topic/topic1/(.*)   topic1/$1   [L]
```

Seems not working. Anyone know how to change this?

Thank you

Comment: I think for wordpress you have to use internal [wordpress mechanism](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) to rewrite don't use .htaccess for this.

Comment: @Abhishekgurjar, I can use [Wordpress Rewrite Rule](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule), but for this I need to write additional codes, I am trying to avoid this. Any solution with `htaccess` would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change `[L]` to `[P]`
final code :

```
RewriteRule ^topic/topic1/(.*)   topic1/$1   [P]
```

Comment: we need to do little changes, `topic1/$1` should be `/topic/$1`. Please update answer then I will mark as correct.